# XPath - get namespace nodes for this node only (i.e. not ancestor nodes)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces

In XSLT, the following XPath retrieves namespace nodes for all namespaces that are **in scope**. These include the namespaces defined for the current node, as well as those defined in ancestors of the current node.

```
<xsl:for-each select="namespace::*">
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to retrieve only the namespace nodes which are explicitly defined for the current node i.e. not those inherited from ancestral scope.

How?

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? Please include a small example of the input and the expected output. Also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is impossible. You can only list namespace nodes that don't match any of the parent's namespace nodes:

```
<xsl:for-each select="namespace::*">
    <xsl:if test="not(../../namespace::*[name() = name(current())] = .)">
        <!-- different -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But this won't list namespace nodes that are redefined with the same prefix and URI as on the parent.

Comment: Good enough for my needs! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to retrieve only the namespace nodes which are explicitly defined for the current node"

Namespace declarations don't form part of the XDM data model: for example if there are duplicate redundant namespace declarations, there's no way of discovering this through XPath, because the namespace information is presented in a normalized form where XDM only tells you what namespaces are in-scope for an element, not where they were declared. The closest you can get is to find the namespaces that are in-scope for an element and not for its parent, which @nwellnhof has shown you.